# CSS animation on the container instead of on the link

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a CSS border animation on an HTML link. The animation sets on mouse hover and it automatically adjusts to the with of the link. Once the mouse is hover, border animations appear in pairs, left-right + top-down. When the animation is over the borders will form a square around the link.

It works fine until the link gets a line break and instead of one line I have a link with two lines. In that case the animation will form around the top line in the link and ignore the line break.

I have been trying and trying and I cannot figure out a way to make the animation go around the whole link instead of only around the first meaning. Can anyone help me out?

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/jo-o-figueiredo/pen/KKZOjWM

Thanks in advance!

```css
div.caixa {
  margin: 4em auto;
  padding: 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.sparkle {
  max-width: 10em;
  color: #5a4d1a;
  margin: auto auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #b1d6b1;
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sparkle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.u-hover--sparkle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before,
.u-hover--sparkle::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform .20s;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before {
  border-top: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}

.u-hover--sparkle::after {
  border-left: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-right: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
}

.u-hover--sparkle:hover::before,
.u-hover--sparkle:hover::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: transform .35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element caixa">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
      <a class="sparkle u-hover--sparkle" href="#paket" rel="noopener">Sällskap - 
      Sammankomster</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `.sparkle` to display block so it covers the whole thing.
Also define how your text should break, because if it's a long word, it has no choice to go out of bound by default.

```css
.sparkle {
    display: block;
    word-break: break-all;
    /* rest of your code */
}
```

```css
div.caixa {
  margin: 4em auto;
  padding: 4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.sparkle {
  max-width: 10em;
  color: #5a4d1a;
  margin: auto auto;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #b1d6b1;
  text-underline-offset: 0.5em;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  font-weight: 500;
  
  display: block;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.sparkle:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1a1a1a;
}

.u-hover--sparkle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.75em;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before,
.u-hover--sparkle::after {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: transform .20s;
}

.u-hover--sparkle::before {
  border-top: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  transform: scale3d(0, 1, 1);
}

.u-hover--sparkle::after {
  border-left: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  border-right: 1px solid #1a1a1a;
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
}

.u-hover--sparkle:hover::before,
.u-hover--sparkle:hover::after {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transition: transform .35s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_text_column wpb_content_element caixa">
  <a class="sparkle u-hover--sparkle" href="#paket" rel="noopener">Sällskap - 
      Sammankomster</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I was apparently over complicating the problem here. All my ideas were way more complex. The issue is fixed. Thanks!!

Comment: @user2104321 You're welcome. I also added a snippet with reduced code. The `p` element and the inner `div` aren't required (unless you have other styles that aren't shared here.)

Comment: unfortunately I do need those elements since I am working in Wordpress with a page builder, I don't have full control over the HTML structure. But I am sure your code will be useful for others. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple things to point out:

Easy Fix: Add `display: block;` to the `.sparkle` class and increase max-width to enable the text to stand in one line.

Alternatively you could also apply the animation styles to the divs surrounding the Link

Optional: I think you could also remove the `<p>` element surrounding the link as it is unnecessarily making your markup more complex.